# How to make multiple testcases of one value

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, data-driven

I have created test cases for email but there are multiple negative test cases for email field then how should I pass multiple values in the input field. I have created function.but don't is that should I have to create more than one function for that?

```
@DataProvider(name = "Authentication1")
    public static Object[][] credentials1()
    {

        return new Object[][] { { "12234", " %&^%","gfdgfdg"," dfg","gfdg "} };

    }
@Test(dataProvider = "Authentication1" )
    public void invaliddata(String fname, String lname,String email,String pass,String cpass)
    {
        driver.get("http://google.com");

        WebElement firstname = driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
        firstname.clear();
        firstname.sendKeys(fname);

        WebElement lastname = driver.findElement(By.id("LastName"));
        lastname.clear();
        lastname.sendKeys(lname);

        WebElement mail = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        mail.clear();
        mail.sendKeys(email);

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
        password .clear();
        password .sendKeys(pass);

        WebElement conpassword = driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmPassword"));
        conpassword .clear();
        conpassword.sendKeys(cpass);

        WebElement register = driver.findElement(By.id("register-button"));
        register.click();
```

Comment: instead of multiple time webelement, write only one webelement which contain the parameter and call the method
eg. invaliddata(String fname, String lname,String email,String pass,String cpass, string id)
driver.findElement(By.id(id));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this scenario; you have two options to test your Authentication scenario for multiple test data's:

1) Use Data provider with two-dimensional java object
2) Passing data to DataProvider from Excel sheet

> 1) Use Data provider with two-dimensional java object:

---

Data provider returns a two-dimensional java object to the test method and the test method will invoke M times in a M*N type of object array. For example, if the DataProvider returns an array of 2*3 objects, the corresponding test case will be invoked 2 times with 3 parameters each time.

```
    public class Dataprovider
    {

        WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeTest
        public void setup()
        {
             driver = new FirefoxDriver();
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             driver.get("https://google.com");

        }

        @Test(dataProvider="SearchProvider")
        public void testMethod(String author,String searchKey) throws InterruptedException{
            {

                WebElement searchText = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
                searchText.sendKeys(searchKey);
                System.out.println("Welcome ->"+author+" Your search key is->"+searchKey);

                String testValue = searchText.getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println(testValue +"::::"+searchKey);
                searchText.clear();

                //Verify if the value in google search box is correct
                Assert.assertTrue(testValue.equalsIgnoreCase(searchKey));
            }

        }

        /**
         * @return Object[][] where first column contains 'author'
         * and second column contains 'searchKey'
         */

        @DataProvider(name="SearchProvider")
        public Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider()
        {
            return new Object[][] 
            {
                { "India", "Delhi" },

                { "US", "Los Angles" },

                { "japan", "Tokiyo" }

            };

        }

    }
```

---

> 2) Passing data to DataProvider from Excel sheet:

DataProvider helps to send multiple sets of data to a test method. But here we need to make sure that the array returned by the dataprovider should match with the test method parameters.

Take a simple program in which we will validate login screen by taking multiple usernames and passwords. The annotated method must return object[][] where each object[] can be assigned to the test method one as username and the other parameter as password.

```
public class ReadExcelDataProvider {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    String appURL = "Your baseUrl";

    //Locators
    private By byEmail = By.id("username");
    private By byPassword = By.id("session_password-login");
    private By bySubmit = By.id("signin");

    @BeforeClass
    public void testSetup() {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="empLogin")
    public void VerifyInvalidLogin(String userName, String password) 
    {
        driver.navigate().to(appURL);
        driver.findElement(byEmail).sendKeys(userName);
        driver.findElement(byPassword).sendKeys(password);

        //wait for element to be visible and perform click
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(bySubmit));
        driver.findElement(bySubmit).click();

        //Check for error message
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byError));
        String actualErrorDisplayed = driver.findElement(byError).getText();
        String requiredErrorMessage = "Please correct the marked field(s) below.";
        Assert.assertEquals(requiredErrorMessage, actualErrorDisplayed);

    }

    @DataProvider(name="empLogin")
    public Object[][] loginData() 
    {
        Object[][] arrayObject = getExcelData("D:/sampledoc.xls","Sheet1");
        return arrayObject;
    }

    public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) 
    {
        String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
            Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

            int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
            int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

            arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];

            for (int i= 1 ; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

                for (int j=0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
                    arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arrayExcelData;
    }

    @Test
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```